# Pandas | How to grab rows of a time difference column converted to strings

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I have a time difference column that are time differences between two end times of two different excel sheets(you can see my previous question to get a better idea)and the time difference values are strings. I am trying to find a way to grab all rows where the time difference is great than -15 seconds and a range from 3-5 seconds. Greatly appreciate all of the responses you guys are lifesavers. I am also not sure why it is in a format like "11.0" rather than just "11" not sure how to change this either.

Example of time difference column remember these are in a string format

### time_diff

-11.0

-3.0

1.0

4.0

-2.0

Comment: _greater than -15 seconds and a range from 3-5 seconds_  Wouldn't 3-5 seconds always be greater than -15 ?

Comment: Sorry if it was a bit confusing I would like the those to be two separate conditionals.

1) If a row is -15 seconds or more keep those
2) if the time difference is in a range of 3-5 seconds keep those

Answer (score 0):

To convert from strings:

```
df['time_diff'].astype('float')
```

If the previous function didn't work and you had to clean up the string, use a function like this. "Just an example here"

```
df['time_diff'] = df['time_diff'].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)
```

The conditions are a bit confusing as we have some overlap but, using .loc in pandas we can filter the data like this.

```
a = df.loc[(df['time_diff'] >= 3) & (df['time_diff'] <= 5)]

b = df.loc[df['time_diff'] > -15]
```

.loc documentation
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html